# How to convert integer to char in C?

Tags: c

How to convert integer to char in C?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Or maybe same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026727/integer-to-character-conversion ?

Answer (score 137):

A char in C is already a number (the character's ASCII code), no conversion required.

If you want to convert a digit to the corresponding character, you can simply add '0':

```
c = i +'0';
```

The '0' is a character in the ASCll table.

Comment: The '0' being interpreted by the compiler as representing the ASCII code of the zero character, and given that in ASCII the digits '0' to '9' fill a simple range of codes (48 to 57 IIRC).

Comment: won't work for i >=10

Comment: @user5980143 true, but it is not possible to convert i>9 to a _single_ char

Comment: in a swtich says : error case label does not reduce to an integer constant, but not in a "if"

Comment: `int length = 10;
char len = length + '0';
printf("%c", len);` This gave me `:` for 58 on the ascii chart not `10` that I wanted.  The ascii chart shows that int 10 is actually something called LF (line feed).

Answer (score 40):

You can try atoi() library function.
Also sscanf() and sprintf() would help.

Here is a small example to show converting integer to character string:

```
main()
{
  int i = 247593;
  char str[10];

  sprintf(str, "%d", i);
  // Now str contains the integer as characters
}
```

Here for another Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char text[] = "StringX";
   int digit;
   for (digit = 0; digit < 10; ++digit)
   {
      text[6] = digit + '0';
      puts(text);
   }
   return 0;
}

/* my output
String0
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
String6
String7
String8
String9
*/
```

Comment: In the first example, why did you declare `str[10]` instead of `str[7]` since there are 6 digits and allowing 1 for `'\0'`?

Comment: What does `atoi` have to do with it?

Comment: `atoi` does the opposite of what OP wants.

Comment: latter example will not work if the digit is bigger than 9

Answer (score 23):

Just assign the `int` to a `char` variable.

```
int i = 65;
char c = i;
printf("%c", c); //prints A
```

Answer (score 16):

To convert integer to char only 0 to 9 will be converted. As we know 0's ASCII value is 48 so we have to add its value to the integer value to convert in into the desired character 
hence

```
int i=5;
char c = i+'0';
```

Answer (score 8):

To convert int to char use:

```
int a=8;  
char c=a+'0';
printf("%c",c);       //prints 8
```

To Convert char to int use:

```
char c='5';
int a=c-'0';
printf("%d",a);        //prints 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void main ()
 {
    int temp,integer,count=0,i,cnd=0;
    char ascii[10]={0};
    printf("enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&integer);


     if(integer>>31)
     {
     /*CONVERTING 2's complement value to normal value*/    
     integer=~integer+1;    
     for(temp=integer;temp!=0;temp/=10,count++);    
     ascii[0]=0x2D;
     count++;
     cnd=1;
     }
     else
     for(temp=integer;temp!=0;temp/=10,count++);    
     for(i=count-1,temp=integer;i>=cnd;i--)
     {

        ascii[i]=(temp%10)+0x30;
        temp/=10;
     }
    printf("\n count =%d ascii=%s ",count,ascii);

 }
```