# Converting from a std::vector<int> to a char[] C++

Tags: c++, vector

If I have an integer vector (std::vector) is there an easy way to convert everything in that vector to a char array(char[]) so (1,2,3) -> ('1','2','3')
This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
std::vector<int> v;

for(int i = 1; i  < 10; i++){
    v.push_back(i);
}

char *a = &v[0];
```

Comment: I question why you need to do this.  Also why not convert it to `std::string`?

Comment: You can use `itoa` to go from int to char like you want. std::transform (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) will let you do it on a container.

Comment: What result do you expect for integers larger than 9, or smaller than 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::transform` is the right tool for the job :

```
std::vector<int> iv {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
char ca[10] {};

using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::transform(begin(iv), end(iv), begin(ca), [](int i) { return '0' + i; });
```

If you don't need `ca` to be a C-style array, I'd recommend using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead. The latter needs `std::back_inserter(ca)` in place of `begin(ca)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the char array is dynamically allocated? so it can have variable size

Comment: @AllenHuang You could allocate it with `new` and pass the pointer itself to `std::transform`, but the better idea is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: that worked thanks and I am using a char array because I'm using this with zLib

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as this

```
std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<char> c;
for( int i : v ) c.push_back( '0' + i );
```

to realize why your way does not work you need to learn how integers and symbls represented on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store it in char vector initially?

```
std::vector<char> v;
for(int i = 1; i  < 10; i++){
    v.push_back(i + '0');
}
```

Trick from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279401/47351

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the numbers in a vector then you can use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and a [back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<int> v;

std::vector<char> c;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [](int i){return '0' + i;});
```

However, why not just say:

```
std::vector<char> v;

for(char i = '0'; i < '9'; i++)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::transform` with `std::back_inserter`, maybe something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vI{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<char> vC;
    std::transform(vI.begin(), vI.end(), std::back_inserter(vC), [](const int &i){ return '0'+i; });

    for(const auto &i: vC)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```