# Converting int to char in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

Right now I am trying to convert an int to a char in C programming. After doing research, I found that I should be able to do it like this:

```
int value = 10;
char result = (char) value;
```

What I would like is for this to return 'A' (and for 0-9 to return '0'-'9') but this returns a new line character I think.
My whole function looks like this:

```
char int2char (int radix, int value) {
  if (value < 0 || value >= radix) {
    return '?';
  }

  char result = (char) value;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why should converting `10` to a number return `'A'`? Are you expecting the conversion to be based on hex digits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert integer to char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279379/how-to-convert-integer-to-char-in-c)

Comment: @PM77-1: This one is the better dupe target, as the question is better written. I've closed that one to this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 8):

to convert int to char you do not have to do anything

```
char x;
int y;


/* do something */

x = y;
```

only one int to char value as the printable (usually ASCII) digit like in your example:

```
const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int inttochar(int val, int base)
{
    return digits[val % base];
}
```

if you want to convert to the string (char *) then you need to use any of the stansdard functions like sprintf, itoa, ltoa, utoa, ultoa .... or write one yourself:

```
char *reverse(char *str);
const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

char *convert(int number, char *buff, int base)
{
    char *result = (buff == NULL || base > strlen(digits) || base < 2) ? NULL : buff;
    char sign = 0;


    if (number < 0)
    {
         sign = '-';

    }
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            *buff++ = digits[abs(number % (base ))];
            number /= base;
        } while (number);
        if(sign) *buff++ = sign;
        if (!*result) *buff++ = '0';
        *buff = 0;
        reverse(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This isn't what he wants. He wants to convert the number `9` to the character `'9'`, not `'\11'`

Comment: "to convert int to char you do not have to do anything" - what do you mean by that? If for example `char` is signed, then the behaviour will be implementation defined if the `int` cannot fit into the `char`. Teaching in C has become sloppy over the years. These portability concerns matter.

Comment: @Bathsheba no, it won't be undefined, because it is a narrowing integer conversion. [It is implementation-defined (including signal)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3).

Comment: @Bathsheba but you do not have to do anything .All std lib. char functions have int paratemeters and return int as well ie `char c = tolower('C');`. Narrowing is not the UB.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You are of course correct - I've edited my comment. I will not teach C; it will add to the sloppiness. I don't understand the downvote on this answer btw. Let's reverse it.

Comment: @Bathsheba I would rather say nitpickiness. It is a trivia. putting something potentially larger into a smaller container requires some consideration are care. If someone does not understand it - should not be programming computers as it is much too complicated for him  .

Comment: @PeterJ_01 My comment was before the edit, when it was just `x = y;`

Comment: @Barmar what is the diference between `x=y` and  `char c = tolower('C');` except the believe or faith (function in std library is well written and will not return any worng values :)).

Comment: Corner cases oops: `convert(INT_MAX, ...), convert(-INT_MAX, ...)` work.  `convert(INT_MIN, ..., 10), convert(INT_MIN, ..., 2)` fails.  Interestingly the last 2 fail with "" and "0000000000000000000000000000000".  Certain that `convert(INT_MIN...` invokes UB with `number = -number;` and `digits[number % (base )]`

Comment: @chux yo- sorted

Comment: `INT_MIN` is a pesky case.  With `number == INT_MIN`, `number = -number;` can be the UB.  `if(-number != n) ...;` is too late.

Comment: sorted it another way - brutforce :)

Answer (score 5):

A *portable* way of doing this would be to define a

```
const char* foo = "0123456789ABC...";
```

where `...` are the rest of the characters that you want to consider.

Then and `foo[value]` will evaluate to a particular `char`. For example `foo[0]` will be `'0'`, and `foo[10]` will be `'A'`.

If you assume a particular *encoding* (such as the common but by no means ubiquitous ASCII) then your code is not strictly portable.

Answer (score 2):

Characters use an encoding (typically ASCII) to map numbers to a particular character.  The codes for the characters `'0'` to `'9'` are consecutive, so for values less than 10 you add the value to the character constant `'0'`.  For values 10 or more, you add the value minus 10 to the character constant `'A'`:

```
char result;
if (value >= 10) {
    result = 'A' + value - 10;
} else {
    result = '0' + value;
}
```

Comment: It's odd that folk choose to do it this way given that the portable solution is not particularly more verbose and is probably faster too. I'm sure you know this, but to put it out there, the C standard requires 0 to 9 to be consecutive, but pretty much anything goes for the alphas.

Answer (score 1):

> Converting Int to Char

I take it that OP wants more that just a 1 digit conversion as `radix` was supplied.

---

To convert an `int` into a *string*, (not just 1 `char`) there is the `sprintf(buf, "%d", value)` approach.

To do so to any radix, string management becomes an issue as well as dealing the corner case of `INT_MIN`

---

The following C99 solution returns a `char*` whose lifetime is valid to the end of the block.  It does so by providing a *compound literal* via the macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Maximum buffer size needed
#define ITOA_BASE_N (sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT + 2)

char *itoa_base(char *s, int x, int base) {
  s += ITOA_BASE_N - 1;
  *s = '\0';
  if (base >= 2 && base <= 36) {
    int x0 = x;
    do {
      *(--s) = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[abs(x % base)];
      x /= base;
    } while (x);
    if (x0 < 0) {
      *(--s) = '-';
    }
  }
  return s;
}

#define TO_BASE(x,b) itoa_base((char [ITOA_BASE_N]){0} , (x), (b))
```

Sample usage and tests

```
void test(int x) {
  printf("base10:% 11d base2:%35s  base36:%7s ", x, TO_BASE(x, 2), TO_BASE(x, 36));
  printf("%ld\n", strtol(TO_BASE(x, 36), NULL, 36));
}

int main(void) {
  test(0);
  test(-1);
  test(42);
  test(INT_MAX);
  test(-INT_MAX);
  test(INT_MIN);
}
```

Output

```
base10:          0 base2:                                  0  base36:      0 0
base10:         -1 base2:                                 -1  base36:     -1 -1
base10:         42 base2:                             101010  base36:     16 42
base10: 2147483647 base2:    1111111111111111111111111111111  base36: ZIK0ZJ 2147483647
base10:-2147483647 base2:   -1111111111111111111111111111111  base36:-ZIK0ZJ -2147483647
base10:-2147483648 base2:  -10000000000000000000000000000000  base36:-ZIK0ZK -2147483648
```

---

Ref [How to use compound literals to `fprintf()` multiple formatted numbers with arbitrary bases?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292061/2410359)

Comment: I love this idea for using a macro to supply a function with a compound literal

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

The values stored in a char are interpreted as the characters corresponding to that table. The value of 10 is a newline

Comment: And check out this encoding too while you're at it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Answer (score 0):

So characters in C are based on [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (or UTF-8 which is backwards-compatible with ascii codes). This means that under the hood, "A" is actually the number "65" (except in binary rather than decimal). All a "char" is in C is an integer with enough bytes to represent every ASCII character. If you want to convert an `int` to a `char`, you'll need to instruct the computer to interpret the bytes of an int as ASCII values - and it's been a while since I've done C, but I believe the compiler will complain since `char` holds fewer bytes than `int`. This means we need a function, as you've written. Thus,

```
if(value < 10) return '0'+value;
return 'A'+value-10;
```

will be what you want to return from your function. Keep your bounds checks with "radix" as you've done, imho that is good practice in C.

Comment: "So characters in C are based on ASCII (or UTF-8 which is backwards-compatible with ascii codes)", not necessarily.

Comment: For a beginner, this is enough :P

Comment: I disagree. When I began C, I had portability drummed into me. It's a very important facet of the language. Don't get into bad habits. Before long, your code is littered with UB, and will not compile properly with aggressive optimisations.

Comment: Another thing C doesn't guarantee is that [`'A'`-`'Z'` are consecutive values](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/codes/ebcdic.html) :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Absolutely. But it *does* guarantee `'0'` - `'9'` are consecutive.

Comment: Peter's code is not more complicated than this but it is guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Absolutely again. And it's probably faster. Why dump portability when the portability solution is quicker?

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Converting `int` to `char` by type casting

Source File **`charConvertByCasting.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 66;              // ~~Type Casting Syntax~~
    printf("%c", (char) i); //  (type_name) expression
    return 0;
}
```

Executable **`charConvertByCasting.exe`** command line output:

```
C:\Users\boqsc\Desktop\tcc>tcc -run charconvert.c
B
```

Additional resources:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

### 2. Convert `int` to `char` by assignment

Source File **`charConvertByAssignment.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 66;
    char c = i;
    printf("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Executable **`charConvertByAssignment.exe`** command line output:

```
C:\Users\boqsc\Desktop\tcc>tcc -run charconvert.c
B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
char a;
a = '0' + 5;
```

You will get character representation of that number.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the idea from the existing answers, i.e. making use of array index.
Here is a *"just works"* simple demo for **"integer to char[]"** conversion in base 10, without any of `<stdio.h>`'s `printf` family interfaces.

Test:

```bash
$ cc -o testint2str testint2str.c && ./testint2str
Result: 234789
```

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char digits[] = "0123456789";

void int2str (char *buf, size_t sz, int num);


/*
  Test: 
        cc -o testint2str testint2str.c && ./testint2str
*/
int
main ()
{
  int num = 234789;
  char buf[1024] = { 0 };

  int2str (buf, sizeof buf, num);

  printf ("Result: %s\n", buf);


}

void
int2str (char *buf, size_t sz, int num)
{
  /*
     Convert integer type to char*, in base-10 form.
   */

  char *bufp = buf;
  int i = 0;

  // NOTE-1
  void __reverse (char *__buf, int __start, int __end)
  {
    char __bufclone[__end - __start];
    int i = 0;
    int __nchars = sizeof __bufclone;
    for (i = 0; i < __nchars; i++)
      {
    __bufclone[i] = __buf[__end - 1 - i];
      }
    memmove (__buf, __bufclone, __nchars);
  }

  while (num > 0)
    {
      bufp[i++] = digits[num % 10]; // NOTE-2
      num /= 10;
    }

  __reverse (buf, 0, i);

  // NOTE-3
  bufp[i] = '\0';
}

// NOTE-1:
//         "Nested function" is GNU's C Extension. Put it outside if not
//         compiled by GCC.
// NOTE-2:
//         10 can be replaced by any radix, like 16 for hexidecimal outputs.
//
// NOTE-3:
//         Make sure inserting trailing "null-terminator" after all things
//         done.
```

*NOTE-1:*
"Nested function" is GNU's [C Extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions). Put it outside if not
compiled by GCC.

*NOTE-2:*
10 can be replaced by **any** radix, like 16 for hexidecimal outputs.

*NOTE-3:*
Make sure inserting trailing "null-terminator" after all things
done.