# How to join two numbers of type char and make them int type

Tags: c, char, concatenation, getline, atoi

Essentially I have a line which ends in two numbers. I can read the numbers eg) '4' and '1'. I want to concatenate them into '41' and then read that as an int type of value 41. Converting a single character to int is straight forward but how would this work for two (or more) characters?

I am grabbing the characters using:

```
int first_digit = ctoi(line[1]);
int second_digit = ctoi(line[2]);
```

where ctoi is defined as :

```
int ctoi( int c ) // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279401/12229659
{
    return c - '0';
}
```

Comment: If you have a 4 for the tens place and a 1 for the ones place, how do you make 41?

Comment: `ctoi` is extremely poorly defined here. You should at least check with `isdigit` from `ctype.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use a function such as `sscanf` (provided that line is a proper *string*)

```c
 int num;
 if (sscanf(line, "%d", &num) != 1) {
    // handle conversion error
  }
```

Although, `scanf` in general doesn't provide protection from arithmetic overflow, so for a **big** number it will fail (and you won't be able to track it).

`strtol` and friends, will fail (and will let you know) when you exceed the range.

You could however build your own function, again with no overflow protection:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int stringToInt(char *str) {
       int num = 0;

       size_t start = (*str == '-') ? 1 : 0; // handle negative numbers

       for (size_t i = start; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
              if (isdigit((unsigned char)str[i]) == 0) { // we have a non-digit
                     exit(1); // ideally you should set errno to EINVAL and return or terminate
              }

              num = (num * 10) + (str[i] - '0');
       }
       return (start) ? -num : num;
}
```